# Parse raw string to list of object

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am getting the List of Links in a raw string value, Is there a way to parse the raws string to a list of objects?

Eg: Raw value: `<links><link id="{xxxxx-xxx-xxx}" linkid="xxxxx-xxx-xxx" text="Visit" linktype="internal" target="blank" title="Visit" querystring="" linktext="Visit" /><link id="{xxxx-xxx-xxx}" linkid="xxxx-xxx-xxx" text="Apply" linktype="internal" target="blank" title="Apply" querystring="" linktext="Apply" /></links>`

To

```
public IEnumerable<Link> Links {get;set;}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a Sitecore-specific issue (I've never used Sitecore and don't know what ti is) but can't you just deserialize the XML?

Comment: Which field type are you using for these links?

Comment: @ddfra Apologies for the late response, my client is making use of fieldsuite and somehow the generalLink was not getting populated via glassmapper/linkfield

Comment: as far as I know the general link allows only 1 value. What I'm saying is that you should get rid of the '<links>' at the beginning and of the '</links>' at the end, then GlassMapper should work. But then the question is: where does that <links> tag came from?

Comment: probably some dev working directly on the raw values? ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var xml=@"<links><link id='{xxxxx-xxx-xxx}' linkid='xxxxx-xxx-xxx' text='Visit' linktype='internal' target='blank' title='Visit' querystring='' linktext='Visit' /><link id='{xxxx-xxx-xxx}' linkid='xxxx-xxx-xxx' text='Apply' linktype='internal' target='blank' title='Apply' querystring='' linktext='Apply' /></links>";

......

using System.Xml.Serialization;
    
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Links));
    
    Links links;

    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        links = (Links)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        
    }
    
foreach (var link in links.Link)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Id: {link.Id} Text: {link.Text} ");
    }
}
```

output

```
Id: {xxxxx-xxx-xxx} Text: Visit 
Id: {xxxx-xxx-xxx} Text: Apply
```

classes

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "link")]
public class Link
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "linkid")]
    public string Linkid { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "linktype")]
    public string Linktype { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "target")]
    public string Target { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "querystring")]
    public string Querystring { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "linktext")]
    public string Linktext { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "links")]
public class Links
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "link")]
    public List<Link> Link { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Serge for providing the solution